# How do I activate the font functions in CKEditor 5 in TYPO3 12?

Tags: typo3, ckeditor, ckeditor5

TYPO3 12 is coming with CKEditor 5, which has a different configuration compared to the previous version 4.

What is the way to use the font functions in TYPO3 12 with CKEditor 5?

I want to use these functions: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html

However, I don't get anything to show up in the toolbar of CKEditor. The buttons do not appear. The console logs this error:

> toolbarview-item-unavailable Object { item: "fontColor" }

Seems like the necessary plugin is not present.

What configuration is needed to make that work again?

Comment: Just asking, did you download the CKeditor plugin to your local extension and add this to your RTE yaml configuration file. 
    ´externalPlugins:
        font:
            resource: "EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Public/CKeditor/Plugins/font/"´

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it using ```ddev npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font```. However, that downloaded 16 projects with more than 2000 files. I am not sure, whether that is what I need. All I want to do is add one plugin... Should I be able to just import these files? What do I have to do with these files?

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, the error indicates that the plugin is not loaded.
There are at least 2 ways to include the plugin.

#### First Solution

You can use a JavaScript module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to generate an ES6 module of the CKEditor plugin. The generated module can be included like a [custom plugin](https://www.derhansen.de/2023/05/2023-05-05-create-a-custom-ckeditor5-plugin-for-typo3-12.html) to your project.

There are some pitfalls and webpack has to be configured to generate an output that can be used by TYPO3. [CKEditor5-Plugin-Converter](https://github.com/Beronimus/Typo3-CKEditor5-Plugin-Converter) is a small project on Github that converts the fonts plugin for TYPO3 12.4.2.

#### Second Solution

You can [install CKEditor5 plugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/plugins/installing-plugins.html), by adding them to the build process of the CKEditor bundle.
With following steps you can customize the CKEditor bundle used by typo3:

- clone the [typo3 project](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3) from github
- change your working directory to typo3/build
- make sure node is installed and run following npm commands:

  ```
  npm install
  npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-font
  ```
- edit following file by importing the font plugin and adding it to the exports `typo3/Build/Sources/JavaScript/rte_ckeditor/contrib/ckeditor5-bundle.js`
- generate the CKEditor bundle

  ```
  npx grunt update
  ```
- copy the file
  `typo3/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor5-bundle.js` to your extension
- update or add the file `JavaScriptModules.php` in your extension so that it contains following import

  ```
  return [
    'dependencies' => [ 'backend' ],
    'tags' => [ 'backend.form' ],
    'imports' => [
      '@typo3/ckeditor5-bundle.js' => 'EXT:your-extension/path/to/file/ckeditor5-bundle.js',
    ],
  ];
  ```
- configure the RTE yaml configuration in you project

  ```
  editor:
      toolbar:
        items:
          - fontSize
          - fontFamily
          - fontColor
          - fontBackgroundColor
          - ...
  ```

Comment: @Christopher: You a right, that seems to be the right way. But the solutions may be useful for any other plugin written for CKEditor 5, which is not included in the bundle used by TYPO3.

Comment: Concerning solution 2 It keeps to say that the packages for some plugins are already loaded but not included in the build process. This relates i.e. for ' TableCaption'  and in this case nothing should be installed additionally, just the plugin added in the file `typo3/Build/Sources/JavaScript/rte_ckeditor/contrib/ckeditor5-bundle.js`

Comment: Some further hints can be found on https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101874

Comment: Meanwhile there was a small change how Plugins are included in CKEditor in TYPO3.
You can have a look at https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/81397 to see what to change to get the required files built / created.