How can I add the page break feature to a TYPO3 extension
I am trying to create a TYPO3 extension that adds the page break feature to the ckeditor5 in TYPO3 v12.
My extension has the following structure:
rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Configuration/JavaScriptModules.php
<?php
return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'backend'
    ],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    'imports' => [
        '@test/typo3-rte-ckeditor-page-break/plugin.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/JavaScript/CkeditorPlugins/PageBreak/plugin.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break/src/index.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-core.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5/src/core.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-widget.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5/src/widget.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-ui.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/index.js',
    ],
];

rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Configuration/RTE/PluginPageBreak.yaml
editor:
  config:
    importModules:
      - '@test/typo3-rte-ckeditor-page-break/plugin.js'


rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/JavaScript/CkeditorPlugins/PageBreak.plugin.js
import * as Core from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';
import * as UI from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui';

import { PageBreak } from "@ckeditor/page-break.js"

export default class PageBreakPlugin extends Core.Plugin {
    static pluginName = 'PageBreakPlugin';

    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;

        editor.config._config.plugins.push(PageBreak);

        // The button must be registered among the UI components of the editor
        // to be displayed in the toolbar.
        editor.ui.componentFactory.add(PageBreakPlugin.pluginName, () => {
            // The button will be an instance of ButtonView.
            const button = new UI.ButtonView();

            button.set({
                label: 'Page Break',
                withText: true
            });

            // Execute a callback function when the button is clicked
            button.on('execute', () => {
                editor.execute( 'pageBreak' );
            });

            return button;
        });
    }
}

When I click on my page break button that I created, I get the following error: "ckeditor5-utils.js?bust=1712928953:47 Uncaught CKEditorError: commandcollection-command-not-found {"commandName":"pageBreak"}"
I want the plugin to work without users having to install the page break feature themselves (e.g. via node). My plugin should contain all the necessary code so that users only need to install my extension to use the page break feature of ckeditor5 in TYPO3 v12.
What am I doing wrong?

The general procedure how to integrate existing plugins is described here quite well, though it changed a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76523659/1019850

adding an own plugin for CKEditor in TYPO3 is described here: https://www.derhansen.de/2023/05/2023-05-05-create-a-custom-ckeditor5-plugin-for-typo3-12.html

We did something similar with the text-part-language feature. There has to be something off with your JavaScriptModules.php
Have a look and compare your repository with ours > https://github.com/Gugler-GmbH/ckeditor5-language/tree/main
Before adding some custom Code in "@test/typo3-rte-ckeditor-page-break/plugin.js' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/JavaScript/CkeditorPlugins/PageBreak/plugin.js'" I would try to run this plugin natively via:
#RTE Config
editor:
  config:
    importModules:
      - "@ckeditor/page-break"

#JavascriptModules.php
<?php
return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'backend'
    ],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    'imports' => [
        '@ckeditor/page-break' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break/src/index.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-core' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5/src/core.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-widget' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5/src/widget.js',
        '@ckeditor/page-break-ui' => 'EXT:rte_ckeditor_pagebreak/Resources/Public/Contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/index.js',
    ],
  ];

Don't forget to update those js file accordingly to the imports, else ckeditor5 won't find those files.

Thank you! I tried it natively now and it seems like there is only one bug left. Currently I am importing the PageBreak module from the directory you get when you run "npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break". Is this the wrong way to do it? Of course I placed it in my extensions directory. Because now I get this error: CKEditor5 plugin export "default" not available in Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag:) 'Module'}
I am probably making a stupid mistake because I am new to TYPO3 and CKEditor. So thanks a lot for your help!

this is the correct way to go! you import all the sources npm gives you, then you have to check the import commands inside those javascript files. These have to match with the JavaScriptModules.php
if the javascript is loaded but still errors happen, then check those import exports, maybe there is something to change. I had this error too and I think it was because of those import/export. Check your JS Files with ours and look for differences.

Unfortunately, I was still unable to fix it. I checked all the paths and they seem to be correct.
I am getting the following error: CKEditor5 plugin export "default" not available in module: https://imgur.com/a/LlBKOy9
At the moment my JavaScriptModules.php looks like this:
https://imgur.com/a/XjWzf4D
And my index.js (@ckeditor/page-break) looks like this:
export { default as PageBreak } from './pagebreak.js';
export { default as PageBreakEditing } from './pagebreakediting.js';
export { default as PageBreakUI } from './pagebreakui.js';
import './augmentation.js';
